# Fuse-Python: Unable to run example

Tags: python, fuse, xmp

I'm tinkering around with the fuse-python bindings and I can't seem to grasp how to run the example `xmp.py` from the library package (`xmp.py` is located [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/iap/2009/fuse/examples/xmp.py)). Looking at a lecture slide from MIT (located [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/iap/2009/fuse/fuse.ppt)), on slide 33, it shows the command line invoking of `xmp.py`:

```
./xmp.py --o root=/mit/sipb/ /tmp/mntdir
```

(I do `python xmp.py` instead of `./xmp.py` since my ubuntu doesn't understand `./` with python script for some reason)

From what I get out of it, the `root=/mit/sipb` arg is a directory of what you are emulating and `/tmp/mntdir` is where you mount your FUSE FS. So, I try...

```
python xmp.py --o root=/home/chris /tmp/fs
```

...and it doesnt want to run and it complains about the `--o` option. I remove the `--o` option and it runs (`ps ax` shows it running) but the folder `/tmp/fs` becomes corrupt and when I try accessing it I get `cannot access /tmp/fs: Input/output error`.

How do I properly run `xmp.py`?

Thanks!

(I also tried replacing `--o` with `-o` and it still doesn't work.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your script, and on my ubuntu box, with this command line :

```
python xmp.py -o root=/home/chris /tmp/fs
```

it works !

With a `--o` option, it never works ;)

Comment: Worked for me too (on Ubuntu Lucid)

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to this question. I've been really busy. Umm did you check the folder you mounted it to? Did it remain uncorrupted. If so it might be the computer I was using (annoying but workable progress :P)

Comment: @Chris : the folders (the mounted one and the mount point) were totally usable without any problems